# Accessing an object / script in another Unity scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm in the process of creating a simple game as a practice project for transitioning from javascript to C#. I've got a menu set up that will allow the user to select the difficulty of the game, and in another scene (the game world), there is a Game Manager script that will spawn a certain number of enemies based on the difficulty.

The issue I'm having is that I can't seem to dynamically change the value of the difficulty variable in the other scene. It seems to be accessing the remote script/game object fine, but the value doesn't change. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the script files currently, so I can't provide examples of my code. Just looking for a tip or nudge in the right direction, or a "hey you can't do this in this manner". Thank you!

Comment: I think you just need a static variable

Answer (score 0):

For things like this, I like to just use player prefs. With player prefs you could easily save the value in the one scene, and retrieve it later in the other scene. Even better, because it saves the value to disk, when you reopen the application it will retain the previously saved value.

Link to player prefs documentation: 
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

If you did not want to save the setting between game sessions, then global/static variables are also an option, as suggested by Ryan Dansie